# Wordpress next/prev post link with image

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to use an image for the previous and next post links. The following line of code was rejected as I should use the `get_template_directory_uri()`. How should I amend the following code in php to include this function?

```
<?php next_posts_link('<img src="./wp-content/themes/Icecap/images/next.png" />'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're talking about not using `/wp-content/themes/` etc paths.

So, this should work:

```
<?php next_posts_link('<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/next.png" />'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! And you will have to add `?>` right at the end to end off the embedded php, otherwise there'll be syntax error. Wanna amend? `<?php prev_posts_link('<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/prev.png" />'); ?>`

Comment: Ah, yep, my bad - was walking out the door when I put up the answer.